# Does the Roman Catholic Church have a daily Bible reading?

Tags: catholicism, bible

I know that the Roman Catholic Church has the same Gospel reading on the Lord's Day. But does it having a daily reading as well? Where can I go to find it?

Comment: Are you asking about Mass reading or private readings?

Comment: @KenGraham Good question. I thought ktm5124 might be asking about Catholic bible reading plans, too.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

[Divinum Officium](https://isidore.co/divinum/cgi-bin/missa/missa.pl) has Mass [propers](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35841) for the pre-Vatican II, 1962 and earlier calendars; and there is a [daily reading website](http://usccb.org/bible/readings/index.cfm) for *Novus Ordo* Masses.

Comment: Since the linked page at Divinum Officium displays the whole mass and the OP seems unfamiliar with the Catholic liturgy, it seems useful to point specifically to the sections headed "Lesson" and "Gospel".

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are called Mass Readings, you can can see what is available on most Parish or Diocesan websites.

Here is a link to the US Bishops site, giving the readings for today (it will update each day)...
https://bible.usccb.org/daily-bible-reading